# Pattern-matching in for

Tags: scala

There is a following example in Programming in Scala:

```
val fruits = List(Some("apple"), None, Some("orange"))
for(Some(f) <- fruits) println(f)
```

Only apple and orange get printed, because None doesn't match Some(f).

Following this example I would expect this to print "none" once:

```
for(None <- fruits) println("none")
```

but it turns out it prints out:

```
none
none
none
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?